# Android studio Apk not signed in debug variant

Tags: android, gradle, apk

```
Gradle 1.5
```

I am launching my game in four emulators that have differents screen.

It works in 2 emulators just fine , and in 2 emulators it doesnt.

Android studio prompt a message that say:

```
Installation failed since the APK was either not signed, or signed incorrectly.
If this is a Gradle-based project, then make sure the signing configuration is specified in the Gradle build script
```

The error in console:

```
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.darwins.cubegame
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]


Installation failed since the APK was either not signed, or signed    incorrectly.
If this is a Gradle-based project, then make sure the signing configuration is specified in the Gradle build script.
```

I am doing on debug variant, so It should sign it with the debug key store ( it does in 2 of the emulators) but it doesnt in the other 2.

Any way to solve it, or any hint where I can investigate?

All (normal emulators) are ON at the same time

Gradle File

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.darwins.cubegame"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 23
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}

    dependencies {
    compile project(':darwinsEngine2')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
}
```

Comment: Could you paste your build.gradle file please

Comment: Build an release apk and install it on all emulators

Comment: code updated, I cant build a release apk every time I want to test an activity on every screen, it will take so much time